# Retaining n duplicate entries in a file

Tags: bash, sorting

This feels like a Stack Overflow question that folks have already answered but I can't find an appropriate thread.

- there are tools to sort a file to retain unique entries.
- there are tools to sort a file to retain only duplicate entries.
- But... what if I want to specify to keep the first Nth entries of duplicate values, and then discard the rest?

For example, in the list below, I'd like to be able to print out  *up to the Nth* number of duplicates for the first field. Here's the original list:

```
apple    toledo
apple    omaha
apple    butte
apple    freeport
peach    saginaw
peach    frakenmuth
pears    wichita
```

So, for example, the standard `uniq` way of doing things could generate (on an unsorted list):

```
apple toledo
peach saginaw
pears wichita
```

But I might want to keep *up to* 2 duplicate entries:

```
apple toledo
apple omaha
peach saginaw
peach frakenmuth
pears wichita
```

Or if I was feeling crazy, even 3 duplicate entries:

```
apple toledo
apple omaha
apple butte
peach saginaw
peach frakenmuth
pears wichita
```

Is there a sensible way to go about doing this in bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
cat list | awk 'count[$1]++ < 2'
```

You can change the number 2 to 3 or whatever.

Comment: And even remove the cat altogether seeing as awk reads files just fine.

Comment: @grail you mean if your are writing `cat ...` and you are not *concatenating* files, it's probably a *UUOc*? (Unnecessary Use Of `cat`)? Better `awk 'count[$1]++ < 2' file`.